# Not able to access wamp 64 bit when using wifi hotspot of my android device

Tags: wireless-networking, apache-http-server, firewall, android, wamp

I am using wamp (64 bit) server for my android application. When I am connected with my office's wifi and my device is also connected to my office's wifi, at this time my device is able to access my laptop's wamp server.

My laptop has McAfee antivirus. I already open 80 port in MCafee's firewall setting. I have also given access in "Require all granted" in httpd-vhosts.conf file.

Now when I start my device's hotspot and my laptop is connected to that hotstop, After this when my android application try to access wamp server , it is not able to access it. (I already changed the IP in code when I am using wifi hotspot). Now at this time if I disable my McAfee's firewall then it is working.

So my question is that if I use my office's Wifi and my McAfee's firewall is on then also my device is able to access wamp server but When I am using my device's hotspot that time I need to disable my McAfee's firewall.

So my question is what settings I am missing when I am accessing wamp server using my device's Wifi hotspot.

Comment: @Anaksunaman, your comments is the answer I was looking. Can you please add it as answer ?

Comment: I have posted my comment as a (slightly expanded) answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could (perhaps) be an issue with trusted networks. Essentially, depending on what network you are connected to, your firewall may apply different rules to the traffic it handles. I have no experience with McAfee but this is a behavior which is not uncommon in other firewall applications.

In your case, it could be that your office WiFi might be a "trusted" network and thus have fewer restrictions or different rules (such as having different  ports available) than your phone hotspot (which might be considered an "untrusted" network and thus be more restricted).

Assuming this is the case, you will need to adjust your firewall settings to allow the correct traffic (e.g. incoming port 80) while connected to your phone's hotspot network .

Answer (score 0):

If you've enabled your device's hotspot, you're allowing devices that connect with that hotspot to access your cellular data connection. You're not creating an internal network with the connected devices and your phone.

Let me try to clarify. When you're connect your phone and laptop to the office's wifi, you have both devices within the same local network. Traffic is routed within your network only and it doesn't have to travel over the internet.

However, when you create a hotspot on your phone, you typically create your own local network in which your phone only acts as a router to route traffic from the hotspot connected devices (in this case, your laptop) to the internet. The phone itself doesn't participate as a device in this network which means that if you try to connect to the internal IP (the one that the hotspot gave your laptop) from the phone, the phone will go and look for that IP on the internet rather than on the internal network that you created with the hotspot.